# Handle enter key press event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written below lines of code on button click

```
   protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchHint = txtName.Text.Split('[')[0].ToString().Trim();
            WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslCountry", WebUtility.GetDropDownListValue(ddlCountry, String.Empty), false);
            WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslState", WebUtility.GetDropDownListValue(ddlState, String.Empty), false);
            WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslName", txtName.Text, false);
            WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslCity", txtCity.Text, false);
            BindGrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now I want whenever user will press enter key, it should perform the same operation as done in try block in the above code. Please help me in how to handle enter key press event in asp.net c#?

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none" Text="Button" />
```

**JS:**

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            __doPostBack('<%=Button1.UniqueID%>', "");
        }
    }
```

**CS:**

```
 protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SearchHint = txtName.Text.Split('[')[0].ToString().Trim();
        WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslCountry", WebUtility.GetDropDownListValue(ddlCountry, String.Empty), false);
        WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslState", WebUtility.GetDropDownListValue(ddlState, String.Empty), false);
        WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslName", txtName.Text, false);
        WebUtility.SetCookie(Response, "gslCity", txtCity.Text, false);
        BindGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround your controls in a asp:Panel and add the DefaultButton property

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlSurround" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnGo">
    <asp:Textbox id="textBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropdownList id="dropdownList1" runat="server />
    <asp:Button id="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

As long as one of the controls inside that panel has focus, you can hit Enter to execute the button click